# Ember JS Component combine three sources of CSS class names

Tags: ember.js

I want to be able to write a component which has three sources of classNames:

- A set of static classes from the `classNames` property of the component (static JS code)
- A set of user provided classes provided through the classNames property on the HB-helper

Up to here I have tested successfully -- Ember will merge the two sources which I think is nice. I cannot however find where this behaviour is documented.

- Now I want to be able to add further classes to this list with a computed property.

The only way to do this seems to be with `classNameBindings` but this is not sufficient in my case! As the list of classes is quite dynamic and I want to calculate it explicitly.
What I have also tried is to define the `classNames` as `property()` but this seems not to be possible according to [this issue](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/490).

Does anyone know a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

This is one case where I think you don't want to use Ember and instead use jQuery directly. Use Ember to take care of the static classes and the classes provided through the Handlebars helper, but use jQuery to add the computed property classes. For instance, let's says that you have a computed property called `extraClasses`. Try something like this:

```
extraClasses: function() {
    return ['one', 'two', 'three'];
}.property(),

previousExtraClasses: [],

manageClasses: function() {
    var previousExtraClasses = this.get('previousExtraClasses');
    var extraClasses = this.get('extraClasses');

    // Remove the classes that got removed from `extraClasses`
    previousExtraClasses.forEach(function(className) {
        if (extraClasses.indexOf(className) < 0) {
            this.$().removeClass(className);
        }
    }, this);

    // Add the classes that got added to `extraClasses`
    extraClasses.forEach(function(className) {
        if (previousExtraClasses.indexOf(className) < 0) {
            this.$().addClass(className);
        }
    }, this);

    this.set('previousExtraClasses', extraClasses);
).observesImmediately('extraClasses')
```

Every time you update `extraClasses` with a new set of classes, the `manageClasses` observer will take care of managing the classes on the component. As long as `extraClasses` returns an array of strings, it can be computed any way you like.

Comment: Yea, I use a similar pattern now but I hoped there is a jQuery-less way. Will accept your answer soon if no one else suggests something.

Comment: Unfortunately you've got a pretty unique use case, so it's unlikely that Ember has a good way to do this built-in (although I've been wrong before). If it doesn't, I think that writing jQuery in Ember is perfectly fine as long as you encapsulate it properly. Perhaps put it on a base class component or something. As long as the users of your component API don't have to deal with jQuery, you're doing it right.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I fully understood your reasoning against `classNameBindings`. You can get dynamic classes list with help of that property. I've prepared an example in [jsbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qivami/1/edit?html,js,output).

It uses rule that applies to `classNameBindings`: if no conditional classes have been listed (eg. `classNamesBindings: ['isEnabled:enabled:disabled']`), than use provided by computed property class name as is (eg. `true||false` would be in classes list of HTMLElement). So, you need to declare a computed property which returns a string with classes names and to list this CP in component's `classNameBindings`.

Comment: The reason I don't want to do this is because I have 4 different classes (`warning`, `info`, `error`, `success`) and depending on another property `event` I want to select one of them. Realizing this with `classNameBindings` is far to verbose. Something like this you would want to do in a computed property.

Comment: I think that's exactly what I implemented in jsbin. Detailed version (for your case): http://emberjs.jsbin.com/relor/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Ok, I agree this approach works for having a set of classes depending on a single event. But now lets say I need to add/ remove even more classes based on other conditions like `event`. For this to work I would have to set multiple `classNameBindgins` but this is not a solution (too verbose, scattered logic). What I want is a single function which returns a list of classes and this list is calculated with a rather complex logic. Your solution would be ok (but not ideal) if you could return multiple classes from `extraClasses()`.